# Python Discord Bot (run from a .bat file in cmd) doesn't terminate right after closing the window

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, discord, bots

I have been searching for an answer and cannot seem to find it so I'm asking here.

I have a python bot for which I created a simple batch file that activates a venv and then runs the main.py :

```
"C:\Projects\BOT\vnev\Scripts\"activate.bat && start "MyBot" python main.py
```

Bot starts when double clicking the .bat file and a python window shows up logging all the requests...

Problem is when I want to close the bot, if I terminate it using CTRL + C then everything works and Discord Bot goes offline immediately.
But, if I just close the cmd window, then discord Bot is still online for some time when it finally exits by itself. I'm suspecting some kind of multithreading issue? like a thread doesn't quit and instead it quits after a timeout of some kind? Sadly the python bot is not developed by me so I don't exactly know what's up but wouldn't killing the cmd window always force the python bot to kill itself? I'm curious about it and want to understand it a bit more, maybe adding something to my .bat script that terminates the python process in the "right" way?

Comment: Have you tried using the `call` command? ```Call "C:\Projects\BOT\vnev\Scripts\activate.bat" & Start "MyBot" python.exe main.py```. You might not even need `Start`!  ```Call "C:\Projects\BOT\vnev\Scripts\activate.bat" & python.exe main.py```.

Comment: The surefire way to kill something is to grab its Process ID when you run it, then use that to kill the process when ready. But to help you with that we'd need to understand exactly what you were doing, and how, and be able to replicate it and your specific environment.

Comment: I have both tried the "call" command and also tried to kill the python process from the task manager.  Same problem each time, discord bot remains active for a while. Maybe abruptly shutting down the python process doesn't "send" the right termination signal to discord so the bot is actually online.

Comment: The `Call` command is a necessity, not an option! If you do not use it, all of the things  `activate.bat` does are deleted upon it ending and before your `python` command beginning. That would mean you may as well not have used it in the first place. Please update your question with the rest of the information I have already mentioned.

Comment: Using `start` runs the process independently, from the point of view of the caller it looks like it finishes immediately.  You definitely won't get a signal back when it exits.

Answer (score 0):

It finally seems to work with these steps:

1. Changed the .bat file like this:

```
call "vnev\Scripts\activate.bat"
python main.py
```

2. Added a custom function on_exit that is called when cmd receives close signal and basically finish executing remaining asyncio tasks and then stops the main event loop.